# Move huge number of files into date structured directory order

Tags: shell-script, files, rename

I have about 1 million files in this directory: `/home/username/images/`

Each of the files are called something like: `012345678910(Place)_0_20120414185957_28841.jpg` with the timestamp part of the filename changing on each picture.

The code below contains code to sort/move the files into this date structure: `/home/username/sorted/2012/04/14/18/name_of_file.jpg`

For a small sample of files it works fine, but for the huge directory my putty terminal gets disconnected after outputting

```
Directory $newdir does not exist.  Creating same.
```

I had other code which always died with the error code `argument list too long`.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
ALLFILES=(images/*)
for ((i=0; i<${#ALLFILES[*]}; i+=30000));
do
    set $(echo "${ALLFILES[@]:i:30000}" | awk -F_ '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}')
    fullyear=$3
    year=$(echo $fullyear |cut -c1-4)
    month=$(echo $fullyear |cut -c5-6)
    day=$(echo $fullyear |cut -c7-8)
    hour=$(echo $fullyear |cut -c9-10)
    newdir=$(echo /home/username/sorted/$year/$month/$day/$hour/)
    if ! [ -d $newdir ]; then
        echo Directory $newdir does not exist.  Creating same.
        mkdir -p $newdir;
    fi
    mv "${ALLFILES[@]:i:30000}" $newdir;
done
```

Any ideas why the connection will not hold while performing the large loop?

Comment: Have you tried turning on `xtrace` (`set -x` at the beginning or invoke `bash` with `-x`) for debugging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to run it in screen session. Or even try another construction. I believe find + sed will work better then pure bash:

```
find images/ -name "*.jpg" | sed 's%^[^_]*_[^_]*_\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\).*%mkdir -p "/home/username/sorted/\1/\2/\3/\4" \&\& mv "&" "/home/username/sorted/\1/\2/\3/\4/"%'
```

This is just to show, how sed make commands to execute.
Adding `e` after last `%` will force command executing:

```
find images/ -name "*.jpg" | sed 's%^[^_]*_[^_]*_\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\).*%mkdir -p "/home/username/sorted/\1/\2/\3/\4" \&\& mv "&" "/home/username/sorted/\1/\2/\3/\4/"%e'
```

ps. You don't need to use in bash

```
day=$(echo $fullyear |cut -c7-8)
```

Bash can do it itself without `echo | cut` :

```
day=${fullyear:6:2}
```

Comment: I never knew about the sed command. The snippet you gave works perfectly ... well it's been working away for the last few mins generating the folders and moving the files in correct order. This was my first time ever creating a *nix script, I'm coming from Windows. The server I'm connecting to is a web-hosting provider, not mine so I can only use Putty to connect.

Comment: I also didn't know that Bash can do the segmenting of the variables. That's good to know. Thanks very much for your help Rush.

Comment: This will break horribly on special characters in filenames and **is also a security hole** as it allows malicious filenames to cause arbitrary code execution.  See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this shell script in the root of a directory packed with files to move them all to a `year/month`-like structure:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ ! $1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: ./pictures.sh jpg"
    exit 1
fi

for f in *."$1"; do
    FILENAME="$f"
    YEAR=`date -j -f "%s" $(stat -f "%m" "$FILENAME") +"%Y"`
    MONTH=`date -j -f "%s" $(stat -f "%m" "$FILENAME") +"%m_%B"`
    DEST="$YEAR/$MONTH"

    if [ ! -d "$DEST" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$DEST"
    fi

    echo "Moving $FILENAME to $DEST/$FILENAME ..."
    mv "$FILENAME" "$DEST/$FILENAME"
done
```

Usage: `$ ./pictures.sh JPG` to move *.JPG to the correct structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also sorting images into date-structured directories, but I have a slightly different approach. I want my images to go to their respective `YYYY-MM` directories, based on their timestamps. So what I do is that I start by `ls -l *.jpg > tmp.txt` the image folder, then I feed this `tmp.txt` into a loop to get the timestamp for each file. I haven't found a way to get the timestamp otherwise.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
hostdir="/home/Photos/"
destdir="/tmp/sorted"

cd $hostdir

touch /tmp/tmpsort.txt
ls -l *.jpg > /tmp/tmpsort.txt

while read line
do
    filename=$(echo $line | awk '{print $8}')
    filedate=$(echo $line | awk '{print $6}')
    filedir=${filedate:0:7}

    if [ ! -d $destdir/$filedir ]; then
        mkdir -p $destdir/$filedir
    fi

    # Let's skip files that were already sorted from a previous run
    if [ ! -f $destdir/$filedir/$fiename ]; then
        cp $filename $destdir/$filedir/
    fi

done < /tmp/tmpsort.txt
rm /tmp/tmpsort.txt
```

I don't have millions of images to sort and if I did, this code would take quite some time to execute. But it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The following one-liner will create a shell script to move the files to the correct folder based on modified time.

```
find . -type f -not -name ".DS*" -exec stat -f "mkdir -p %Sm; mv \"%N\" %Sm" -t "%Y/%m/%d" {} \; > move.sh
sh move.sh
```

I have excluded .DS* files (-not -name ".DS*") 
Before execute the move.sh, you can edit it to remove the unwanted files.